# How to make image in left side of text in asp.net button?

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I am using ASP.NET in my project. In that I have add a Button With Background Image.

But Image is Locating on Button Left Site As the Below Image Show. I want to make This Image in Very near to the Text.(As I Marked). The Text is in Center of the Button. Is any Way to Do This?.,

[image]

COde -

```
<asp:Button ID="btnKotAdd" runat="server" Text="Kot Addtion"  
                     onclick="btnKotAdd_Click" 
                     style="margin-left: 10%; background-image: url('Images/add.png'); background-repeat:no-repeat; height:35px;"  

                     width="80%" Font-Overline="False" />
```

Thanks In advance.

Comment: From an HTML perspective, the position of the image depends on the size of the text, so you'll have to add the image as content of the button, like the text. I'm not sure how you do that in ASP.NET though.

Comment: You have to use the background position property. Please have a look at this article **http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to adjust the `background-position` of your button image as per your requirement. like this:

```
  style="margin-left: 10%; 
  background-image: url('Images/add.png'); 
  background-repeat:no-repeat; 
  height:35px;
  background-position:30% 0;"
```